# How to implement User Management between site and third party Javascript widgets?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, widget, jwt, single-sign-on

Suppose you have a third party JS widget running inside your webiste. When your page is loaded, that widget is also loaded inside your HTML (from a different domain).

Also imagine that users can login to your website but they also need login to that widget.

What is the best way to implement some kind of user management between your site and that widget so users don't need to login twice?

Would an oauth2/JWT based solution work?